# where to download spring cloud netflix Java API Doc?

Tags: spring-cloud-netflix

Where to download the Java API doc for spring cloud netlix

Looking for something like this.
https://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/5.2.9.RELEASE/

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Answer (score 0):

This is current Spring Cloud Netflix API [Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/).

Comment: I am looking for Java API doc, not the reference guide.  Example: Spring Framework https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/ has both Java API doc and Reference Doc. But Spring Cloud Netflix https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/  does not have Java API doc.